# Can we say that the analytic function $f$ on

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we say that the analytic function $f$ on $D=\{z \in \mathbb C~:~|z|<1\}$ defined by $$f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{z-2}$$ has the property $$|f(z)|\leq 1,~~~\forall z \in D~~~~$$

Comment: It is $-\frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}$ so it is an automorphism of the disc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ |f(z)|^2 = \frac{|2z-1|^2}{|z-2|^2} = \frac{4|z|^2-2(z+z^*) +1}{|z|^2-2(z+z^*)+4} = 1 + \frac{3|z|^2-3}{|z|^2-2(z+z^*)+4} = 1 +  \frac{3(|z|^2-1)}{|z-2|^2}$$
Therefore for $|z|^2<1$ we have $|f(z)|^2 <1$.